# Avoid adding if/else logic inside view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I was asked to avoid adding logic like like if/else inside views.At the moment I am developing the login/register functionality of the page and I have to display a set of links if a user is in a role and another if he is in another role.

This is what I have done so far:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Products", "Books", "Home")</li>
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    { 
         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log Out" ,"LogOut","Account")</li>
    }
    else
    {
         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log In" ,"LogIn","Account")</li>
    }
    @if(User.IsInRole("administrator"))
    {
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Product Manager", "Books", "ProductManager")</li>
    }
</ul>
```

This code is stored inside the _Layout.cshtml file.I would like to avoid adding the logic into the view.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Why is logic like this in the view such a bad thing?

Comment: the hole point of mvc is separating logic , markup and data so I believe that this is a bad practice of doing things

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily non-mvc, this logic relates solely to the view.

Comment: May be just removing the business logic from the view will suffice? If `if/else` block inside view were going against concepts of the framework, why would they be supported by view engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to do it in the view, I think you'd have do it in the controller. Something like this would work for removing conditional statements from individual views:

```
// controller
ActionResult MyAction()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        ViewBag.MenuControl = "Menu/NotLoggedIn"
    } 
    else if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
    {
        ViewBag.MenuControl = "Menu/Administrator"
    } 
    else
    {
        ViewBag.MenuControl = "Menu/LoggedIn"
    }

    ...
}

// view
@Html.Partial(ViewBag.MenuControl);
```

Or to share this logic across many views, I suggest you create a specific MenuController for housing this logic.

```
ActionResult RenderMenu()
{
    string template;
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        template = "Menu/NotLoggedIn"
    } 
    else if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
    {
        template = "Menu/Administrator"
    } 
    else
    {
        template = "Menu/LoggedIn"
    }

    return View(template);
}

// view
@Html.Action("RenderMenu", "MenuController")
```

*However*... there is big difference between "view logic" and "controller logic". After all that's one of the main reasons why we want keep views separate from controllers in MVC architectures. A simple rule like "avoid all conditional statements in views" really misses the point of how MVC is designed.

I really prefer doing this in the view because, in reality it has more to do with how to format the view than how your controller should function. I'd stick with your current code.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is nothing wrong with having `if/else` statements in your views. The problem lies with the actual conditional statements themselves.

Take this for instance:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("administrator"))
{
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Product Manager", "Books", "ProductManager")</li>
}
```

Here you are mixing business logic with view logic. You are referencing the name of a role. This has nothing to do with a view. To get around this, try this:

**Model Code**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool IsAdministrator { get; }
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
myModel.IsAdministrator = User.IsInRole("administrator");
```

**View Code**

```
@if(this.Model.IsAdministrator)
{
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Product Manager", "Books", "ProductManager")</li>
}
```

Comment: +1 For pointing out that the *IsAdministrator* test should be in a model.

Answer (score 1):

The hole point of MVC is to separate areas of responsibility. The model has to be completely independent, that is to know only about itself. Having presentation-related logic in the model is pretty normal unless you mix it with the business logic. In your example the obvious improvement could be to move all authorization information into the model object and leave if/else logic in view.

**Controller:**

```
model.IsAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
model.IsAdministrator = User.IsInRole("administrator");
```